# How to generate permutations of a list without “moving” zeros. in Python

Tags: python, list, permutation

using the `itertools` tool, I have all the possible permutations of a given list of numbers, but if the list is as follows:

```
List=[0,0,0,0,3,6,0,0,5,0,0]
```

`itertools` does not "know" that iterating the zeros is wasted work, for example the following iterations will appear in the results:

```
List=[0,3,0,0,0,6,0,0,5,0,0]

List=[0,3,0,0,0,6,0,0,5,0,0]
```

they are the same but `itertools` just takes the first zero ( for example ) and moves it at the fourth place in the list and vice-versa.

The question is: how can I iterate only some selected numbers and left alone others such like zero ? it can be with or without `itertools`.

Comment: Use something like `output2 = list(set(output))`, where `output` is what you got from `itertools`.

Comment: I need to iterate some numbers in all the positions inside the list, leaving alone the zero.

Comment: and there you are . (my new, third approach, answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voilá - it works now - after getting the permutations on the "meat", I further get all possible combnations for the "0"s positions and yield
one permutation for each possible set of "0 positions" for each permutation 
of the non-0s:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

def permut_with_pivot(sequence, pivot=0):
    pivot_indexes = set()
    seq_len = 0
    def yield_non_pivots():
        nonlocal seq_len
        for i, item in enumerate(sequence):
            if item != pivot:
                yield item
            else:
                pivot_indexes.add(i)
        seq_len = i + 1

    def fill_pivots(permutation):
        for pivot_positions in combinations(range(seq_len), len(pivot_indexes)):
            sequence = iter(permutation)
            yield tuple ((pivot if i in pivot_positions else next(sequence)) for i in range(seq_len))

    for permutation in permutations(yield_non_pivots()):
        for filled_permutation in fill_pivots(permutation):
            yield filled_permutation
```

(I've used Python's 3 "nonlocal" keyword - if you are still on Python 2.7,
you will have to take another approach, like making `seq_len` be a list with a single item you can then repplace on the inner function)

**My second try** (the working one is actually the 3rd)

This is  a naive approach that just keeps a cache of the already "seen" permutations - it saves on the work done to each permutation but notonthe work to generate all possible permutations:

```
from itertools import permutations

def non_repeating_permutations(seq):
    seen = set()
    for permutation in permutations(seq):
        hperm = hash(permutation)
        if hperm in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(hperm)
        yield permutation
```

Comment: now you need to take a look at partitions of n where n is the number of zeros in the original list. The number of non-zero elements (k) is also important as they define the permissible partition types. for instance if k = 3 as in example above each partition can be expressed as a sum of k+1 values but not more.

Comment: @V.Petretto but you do not want them fixed, do you??

Comment: no, I don't want them fixed, let me write an example of output: [0,0,1,0,8] [0,1,0,8,0] [1,0,8,0,0] [1,8,0,0,0] [8,0,1,0,0] and so on

Comment: (leaving this just to remark the comments above were about an earlier version of this answer. The current algorithm does permute the 0's)

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Append each result to a List. Now you'll have every single possible combination and then do the following:

```
list(set(your_big_list))
```

Set will narrow down the list down to only the unique permutations. 
I'm not wholly sure if this is the problem you're trying to solve or you're worried about performance.
Regardless just made an account so I thought I'd try to contribute something

Comment: the only problem i see with your approach is that it is computationally inefficient. There has to be a better way.

Comment: yes, the problem I'm trying to solve is for performance and speed. using large lists of numbers, for example of 30 or more, the program works too much time, and a lot of work is wasted, ergo not efficient.

Comment: `Set` and `List` are not even Python built-ins. Maybe you meant `list` and `set`

Comment: Not to mention this does throw away not only all but one zeros (and their position)  long with any other repetitions

Comment: Yeah fixed those capitalization issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is unclear, but if you are trying to list the permutations without having `0` in your output, you can do it as follows:

```
from itertools import permutations
def perms( listy ):
    return permutations( [i for i in listy if i!=0])
```

Comment: i don't think that this is what he wants but this can be the basis for it. you can now impregnate your permutations with 0s to generate even more combinations each of which has the length of the original list ☺

Comment: I need the 0 in the output but I don't need it to be part of the permutation. this to avoid duplicate output and loss of cpu work. maybe I can create a base list of zeros and then insert the permuted numbers in it ?